# Is there any way to find out if the file is being scanned by antivirus?

Tags: filesystems, anti-virus, windows-server-2012-r2

I wonder if there is any indirect way to find out if a certain file is being frequently scanned by antivirus installed on the server?

Comment: "File"? What type of "file"? Unless it's an executable, there is [almost] no reason to scan it at all.

Comment: it is a database file,

Comment: There's no reason at all to scan a file with no active/executable component.

Comment: @Tetsujin good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any file not in an exceptions list can/could be scanned at any point in time. It also depends if on-access scanning is set, and what the file type is. A full scheduled system scan would scan any specified drives, unless the explicit file type(s), folder(s) and/or drive(s) are configured as exceptions.

The only way to see if a file is currently being scanned is to monitor your AV logs on the client, afaik.

Comment: Plus, most AVs scan once, store a hash & don't bother again unless the file/app changes. Most of them also completely ignore anything not executable.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank for pointing it out. However I have a file which changes every seconds. I do not have an access to AV logs unfortunately

Comment: If you know it's safe, then add an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it if you enable auditing on the system, if you do the event log will show that a file is being read by a process, if the process is an AV then you can see it by looking at the log.

If you are a software developer you can

1. look at the application listed in the registry as an antivirus engine,
2. Look if the app has a process (is running) the app
3. Look if any other executable from the folder where the app is is running as a process
4. Take the list of processes and query the operating system for open file handles by process id,

Then you know what files are opened by the anti-virus.